# How to run multiple instances of a Spring Boot Application via a script

Tags: spring, bash, spring-boot, shell, command

I need to create 20 instances of a Spring Boot Application. Is there anyway to automate it so that the below command can be run multiple times and increment the port number each time:

> mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8001

Furthermore once the instances are all started up, is there a way to send an identical POST request with a JSON body to each instance at an endpoint on the Spring Boot Application /someEndpoint.

Comment: You need an loop and a counter.

Comment: What operating system are you using to run this? You could use a bash script but that assumes you're using an operating system like OSX or Linux. If you are on windows you would use a powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a script (.sh file ) in which run a loop for desired time for the command. Use --server.port=0 which will randomly select the port.